# mixed mode debugging in vs2010 with .net 3.5

Tags: c++, debugging, command-line-interface, mixed-mode

For some strange reason, I just can't get VS2010 to stop at breakpoints in managed code within my solution.
I am working solely in C++ and C++/CLI.

two projects:

- One DLL compiled with /clr.
- One .exe compiled without /clr so its a native win32, console app.
- debugger set to /Mixed for both projects.

What works:

- debugging within the native project.
- debugging within native code inside the dll.
- Loading of PDB files is shown within the Debug Output for both dll and exe.

Notes:
 - when I run the app via the internal Debugger(F5), it shows “The breakpoint will not currently be hit” message for all the breakpoints it effectively skips.
 - I have read A LOT of posts and discussions here and elsewhere and the common switch to /mixed mode debugging just doesn't change anything (its already set).

possible answers?
 - somethings I am wondering is if my current predicament could be because I only have VS2008 ***express*** installed. In order to be able to use C++/CLI with .net 3.5 which I require to access third-party 2008 compiled assemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seems like installing a full version of vs2008 was the answer.  I ended up rebuilding my project in 2008 entirely for it to work properly.

I really don't mind since vs2010 lost the intellisense for C++/CLI, it actually feels like an upgrade going back to 2008.

Btw, Recent downloads for vs2008 do not require purchased keys anymore.